# How to repeat option with filenames?

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I have a command which is of the form

```
#!/bin/bash

command -f hello.txt -f world.txt -f bonjour.txt
```

`hello.txt`, `world.txt` and `bonjour.txt` are files which are in the directory `/directory`.

Since in reality there are 50 or 60 such files (and they change), I would like to generate the "`-f`" parts after `command`.

This would have been easy if the command was (just one `-f`)

```
command -f hello.txt world.txt bonjour.txt
```

because I would have gone for

```
command -f $(ls /directory)
```

**Is there a simple way to join `-f` and elements from `ls /directory`?**

I am looking for the equivalent of the Python

```
"-f " + " -f ".join(['hello.txt', 'world.txt', 'bonjour.txt'])
```

where `['hello.txt', 'world.txt', 'bonjour.txt']` is a generated list.

Comment: Note that you should not use `$(ls /directory)` but just `command -f directory/*` – otherwise the expansion will fail when filenames contain whitespace: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs. Anyway, that's not a solution for your issue, I've been looking for a duplicate but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build the variable using a `for` loop.

Because you're using Bash, you should use an array variable, because command-line arguments are in fact an array and not a single flat string. This would avoid various quoting-related problems:

```
args=()
for file in /directory/*; do
    args+=(-f "${file##*/}")
done
mycommand "${args[@]}"
```

For the same reason, avoid `$(ls)` when you can use built-in wildcards i.e. `*`.

If you're writing for baseline POSIX shell and not specifically for Bash, you need to use string variables but you can still use `*` to get the file names, as well as `for` to join them together:

```
args=""
for file in ...; do
    args="$args ..."
done
mycommand $args
```

There are more compact ways of writing this, but they're neither easier to read nor significantly faster.

Answer (score 1):

I would use automatic expansion with printf like this:

`command $( printf -- '-f %q ' *.txt )`

which would result in a command like this, depending on whatever .txt files reside in your directory:

`command -f hello.txt -f world.txt -f bonjour.txt`